# Missing org.andengine.BuildConfig class

Tags: android, andengine

I have installed **ADT 20** and I recently downloaded andengine with examples. But I notice that `import org.andengine.BuildConfig;` file does not exist, because of which I can't compile my project.

According to this [link](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/issues/73), installing ADT 17 or higher should solve this problem.

Has anyone else faced this issue and solved it?

Comment: This class is automatically generated. Cleaning and rebuilding the project should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is to add BuildConfig class as it is written here - https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine. After this I've build the project without any errors. But when I wanted to compile the project, BuildConfig duplicate error showed up. I have looked into gen directory and it turns out the BuildConfig was added there after build. So, I removed the BuildConfig class added manually to package root and just imported the class from gen directory where needed.

This worked on Intellij IDEA 12.

In order not to perform all these steps, just try to build/rebuild the project in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and, in Eclipse, this solved it for me:

In Project Explorer,

1. Make sure you have AndEngine and all its dependencies installed, built and added to your workspace.
2. Right-click on the project folder and select properties.
3. Select android from the left pane.
4. In the right, pane in the Library box, click Add, select AndEngine and hit OK.
5. Add the missing import statements and you should be good to go.
6. If you tried to include AndEngine in any other way, prior to following the instructions above, you may want to clear it out so your project folder is less cluttered (might cause problems later if you don't).

Hope that helps for those using Eclipse.